# Use of mobile Actions icon on Desktop?

Tags: gui-design, navigation, icons, design

Looking for help in designing a navigation method (visual affordance) for space constrained Desktop app.

Below, I have a tree grid which is the primary navigation for the detail pane below the grid. Each level within the grid can have multiple nodes/children.

(It is possible for the user to basically hide the grid via a slider or to maximize the grid via the same method.)

Specific questions are:
1. Arrow up icon next to a **3rd Level Name** for moving up in the grid from the navigation panel. Is this viable? Intuitive? planning for a mouseover. Is there a more elegant way- Win 8?- way to do this?

2. Next to the **4th Level** label and dropdown control, I have a mobile (iOS) Actions icon with a menu of actions- is this mixing metaphors? Is there a better icon or even better paradigm? Space is an issue.

The goal between these two (and they are a bit redundant here, but this is to explore options not final desing) is to enable a user to navigate the hierarchy from the details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Arrow up icon next to a 3rd Level Name for moving up in the grid from the navigation panel. Is this viable? Intuitive? planning for a mouseover. Is there a more elegant way- Win 8?- way to do this?

Because your navigation structure looks just like a spreadsheet (which is very familiar for most people), I would say the navigation should be like a spreadsheet as well. That means as a user I would like to click on a level and then navigate to that level. Other navigation methods like the arrow you suggested (which is my opinion isn't very clear as a navigation button) could cause confusion. An axception to this would be navigating with keyboard arrows (up/down).

> Next to the 4th Level label and dropdown control, I have a mobile (iOS) Actions icon with a menu of actions- is this mixing metaphors? Is there a better icon or even better paradigm? Space is an issue.

Using these kind of mobile icons could be a good practice because lots of people recognize them, but you should be aware of picking the right ones to avoid confusion. I'm not an iOS user myself so I can't say whether or not the icon you chose is the correct icon for an "Action" menu.

Comment: The arrow up icon will have a mouseover. We tested with the business and they "got it" right away. Also, the tree grid echos the navigation- clicking on a level in the tree grid will navigate the user to that node. That functionality currently exists, so the user pattern is there.

Comment: Oh, and the reason for the 'up arrow' is because the user asked to be able to navigate directly to the parent of the item they are on- without having to use the grid. The user will have the ability to hide/collapse the grid, to make more room for the forms at the bottom, and their work flow frequently takes them up the navigation (which is a many to one). There is not a workflow to go the other direction, because there are many children to one parent.

Answer (score 0):

The icon you've shown is [the "Share" icon in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) ([and now Mountain Lion](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167854/up_close_with_mountain_lion_sharing.html)). "Share" doesn't map perfectly to performing actions on an item (although it does somewhat now that the sheet contains functions like printing). To me, the share icon in iOS maps closely to [the "Share" charm in Windows 8](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-charms-142999):

[image: The Windows 8 Share charm]

In OS X, the convention for general actions is a cog. Here it is in the Finder and Mail respectively:

[image: The Actions button in OS X Finder] [image: The actions button in Apple Mail]

Interestingly, the same icon is now used for Smart Playlists in iTunes:

[image: The actions button in iTunes 11]